# Вылетает сессия xrdp на Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, xrdp

DigitalOcean,
Ubuntu 12.04.5 x64 (2G/2CPUs).

Установил xrdp (без Х11). После подключения при запуске какого-либо ресурсоёмкого приложения (Mozilla) вылетает сессия.

До этого был тариф с 1G/1CPUs и подобная проблема наблюдалась, но крайне редко.

Почему с увеличением ресурсов сервера начала вылетать сессия xRDP? Словно, их стало, наоборот, меньше.

Comment: *Почему с увеличением ресурсов сервера начала вылетать сессия xRDP?* — т.е., причину падения (непонятно, кстати, чего именно) вы уже установили. тогда ответ на вопрос самоочевиден.

Comment: Основным критерием работы RDP для меня является запуск Mozilla. Установил x11rdp и очень рад работе нескольких сессий без вылета. Пока проверяю, не рано ли я ликую.

Comment: Установка пакета x11rdp решила проблему.

Comment: напишите, пожалуйста, полноценный ответ, или удалите вопрос вовсе.

Answer (score 1):

Установка пакета x11rdp решила проблему.